# Combining two features on one pie map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, chart

I want to show a pie presentation of the number of mosquitoes caught in each trap, where the size of the circle is the proportion of mosquitoes in one trap out of the total mosquitoes caught, and on top of that, I want to color each circle according to another parameter, which is how much more or less each point is in relation to the last trappings (in percentage, of proportion). For instance, a large circle for a big proportion of mosquitoes caught, and a red color for increase from last time. small circle for few mosquitoes and green for decrease from last time.

How do I combine the two?

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are in the same featureclass have you tried using the "Multiple Attributes" Option "Quantity by Category" in the Symbology section of the properties?

[image: Screenshot with a random point file I have]

If the figures are not in the same featureclass I would join them so I could use this symbology option.